# Is there a standard C source file for compiler test?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction

I am writing a C instrumentation tool. It seems to be working. But I am not 100% sure if it can handle all scenarios.

I am wondering if there are some standard C files test suite that contains all possible C language syntax structures. I guess such file should exist for compiler/parser test purpose.

I am not an expert in this domain. Anyone could shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to test your compiler, try compiling code from an [Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest)

Comment: A linux distribution would be another good test.

Comment: Have you tried searching online? "c compiler tests" should yield some useful results, for starters.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks. I never know that *funny* contest.

Comment: @Evert I tried some search. Such as *standard test suite for c compiler*. I will try more. Thanks.

Comment: @user3386109 a Linux distribution if  you mean the kernel, uses extensions.